# Flexbox Force Scroll To Bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am attempting to build a Chat UI that works cross browser. I am running into a problem where I can't get the `chat-body` div to stay scrolled to the bottom on page load, and when a new message is added.

When logging the `scrollTop` for the `chat-body` div, it is always returning `0` even if you're scrolled. So using JavaScript appears to be out of the question; which is preferred anyways.

So how can I get this div to stay scrolled to the bottom?

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggjewM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was a combination of [dommmm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5610732/dommmm)'s answer, and [thamizhanda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7526926/thamizhanda)'s answer. The final solution was to add the following method and call this in `addMessage()`, as well as in `mounted()`.

```
scrollToBottom(force) {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    let chat = document.getElementById('chat');
    let shouldScroll = chat.scrollHeight - chat.clientHeight <= chat.scrollTop + 1;

    if (force || shouldScroll) {
      chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight - chat.clientHeight;
    }
  });
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/ellisthedev/pen/BpPrGm)

Answer (score 1):

From your demo, the scrollable div is actually `.chat-content` instead of `.chat-body`.

You'll have to watch the scroll position for the correct div. For posterity, you can add a method which runs during `mounted()`:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {...},

  mounted() {
    this.stubMessages();
    this.setScrollPos();
    this.watchScroll();
  },

  methods: {
    setScrollPos(){
      var cBody = document.querySelector('.chat-content');
      cBody.scrollTop = 99999999; // arbitrary/calculated value to get to the end of the div
    },

    watchScroll() {
      var cBody = document.querySelector('.chat-content');
      // watch scroll position of content area
      cBody.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
        console.log('scroll', cBody.scrollTop);
      });
    },

    stubMessages() {...},

    addMessage() {...}
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have added one method called `scrollDown` which used to set the scroll to down when new message added. And i called that function in `addMessage()`

```
methods: {

scrollDown() {
    var chtbody = document.querySelectorAll('.chat-content')[0];
    chtbody.scrollTop = chtbody.scrollHeight;
  },
  stubMessages() {...
  },

  addMessage() {
    this.messages.push({
      text: this.message,
      time: moment()
    });
    this.scrollDown();
    this.message = '';

  }

}

});
```